# How to sync folders on different partitions (symlink?)

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, symbolic-link, fat32

I use Ubuntu One to synch my home/Documents folder among more computers. On a portable tablet I have set the Documents folder in a separate Fat32 partition named sda6, and I made it default documents folder with Ubuntu Tweaks.

How do I synchronize it with my /Documents cloud ? I tried to link /sda/Documents in my home folder but it didn't succeed: UbuntuOne still tries to set an own Documents folder and doesn't let me sync the linked folder with the cloud. What can I do, would please anyone help me ?

Answer (score 5):

Found this in the Ubuntu Community Documentation for the mount command [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount)

> An interesting ability of mount is it's ability to move specific parts of a filesystem around. For example:
>
> ```
> sudo mount --bind /mnt/Files/Music /home/user/Music
> ```
>
> Will let the folder "/mnt/Files/Music" also be accessible in /home/user/Music

This has allowed me to be able to sync my AddOns folder for World of Warcraft between several computers, even though the actually folder is kept on a different hard drive in a ntfs partition. Ubuntu One doesn't support symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

**Right Click** on  **Documents** Folder > **Ubuntu one** > **Sync this folder**

[image]

Then On Client Side My Laptop Open **Ubuntu One** , click **`sync locally`**

[image]

[image]

Done .

---

Example , Document Folder From Desktop to Laptop

## Desktop

[image]

On Laptop Documents

## Laptop

[image]

---

Example , Document Folder From Laptop to Desktop

## Laptop

[image]

## Desktop

[image]

Comment: This big lack hasn't been solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is create a bind mount.

Here's some simplified steps assuming you know a little about mounting:

1. Create a directory to mount in home: mkdir ~/Documents
2. Create a directory as a mount point for the partition: sudo mkdir -p /mnt/SharedPartition
3. Get the device id for your partition: sudo blkid
4. Edit your fstab (By device id is used in UUID (also use your home directory):

```
UUID=4B38-4ED2                  /mnt/SharedPartition  vfat auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,utf8  0  2
/mnt/SharedPartition/Documents  /home/john/Documents  none bind 0 0
```

1. sudo mount -a
2. You can now sync ~/Documents with Ubuntu One

Comment: What ist this command for: /mnt/SharedPartition/Documents /home/john/Documents none bind 0 0
When I type it, he says me: "it's a directory"

Comment: @user37155 Sorry, looks like it got formatted incorrect, that was the bind mount to add to fstab

Comment: Sorry, that for  me a too risky solution

Comment: That line is not a command, it's to be inserted into your `/etc/fstab` file. This is the same solution as the top one. user37155 would you be so kind as to accept an answer, both answers appear to answer the question you asked.